# issue of making a contour plot by matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I have an 11 x 11 data array and try to make a contour plot.

```
fig3=plt.figure(3)
contour_qe=plt.contourf(x_sqr,y_sqr,p_sqr,cmap=cm.coolwarm,shading='flat')

fig3.colorbar(contour_qe,shrink=0.5,aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

the x_sqr, y_sqr and z_sqr are 11x11 array. 
The figure I got is like following:
[image]

There are many empty spaces in the figure... What I like to get is like:
[image]

The triangle mesh is not essential. square mesh also OK.

How can I generate that? I tried both "pcolormesh， contourf" , not work either.

Comment: Of course the data is unknown so one cannot say anything about the result you obtain, but intuitively one would use `plt.tricontourf` or `plt.tripcolor` when the data does not lie on a rectilinear grid.

Comment: using tricontourf is works. Thanks!